# Prove by induction that...

Tags: elementary-number-theory, induction

If $0<a<1$. Prove by induction that $\forall n \in \mathbb N, (1-a)^n < \frac{1}{1+na}$.
I know that induction requires a base case and an induction hybothethis (IH).
For the base case, n = 1: 
LHS = (1-a)^1 = 1-a
RHS = $\frac{1}{1+a}$ 
So $1-a < \frac{1}{1+a}$. By testing out a few numbers, I know this inequality is true. But how do I show the base case formally?
The IH would be: "Assume $(1-a)^k < \frac{1}{1+ka}$ for some natural number k," right?
Then I need to show that $(1-a)^{k+1} < \frac{1}{1+(k+1)a}$? Which I have no idea how to do.
Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Edit: For the base case, I did
$1-a < \frac{1}{1+a} <=> (1-a)(1+a)<1 <=> 1-a^2<1 <=> a^2 >0$ which is True since a>0, so $a^2>0$

Comment: In your edit, I would have expected the last step to be $1 - a^2 < 1 \iff 0 < a^2$ which is true (because $a \ne 0$).

Comment: Thanks, I've corrected it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By hypotesis
$$(1-a)^{k+1} =(1-a)^k (1-a)< \frac{1-a}{1+ka}$$
and then
$$\frac{1-a}{1+ka}<\frac{1}{1+(k+1)a} \Leftrightarrow (1-a)(1+(k+1)a)<1+ka \Leftrightarrow \\ \Leftrightarrow -(k+1)a^2<0$$

Comment: How did you get the last step? (1-a)(1+(k+1)a) < 1+ ka <=> a<(2k+2)/k+1.

Comment: I got that $(1-a)(1+a(k+1)) < 1+ak <=> 1+ak-a^2k-a^2 < 1 + ak <=> 1 - a^2k - a^2 < 1 <=> 0 < a^2(k+1)$. Then because $a^2>0$ and k is natural number >0, thus  $a^2(k+1)$ is positive. Is that right as well?

Comment: Yes, you are right.